# Log4Net Webservice not creating file, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, logging, log4net

I'm trying to use Log4Net which logs to a file in a ASP.Net site but my implementation just does just not create the file. I looked a thousand times over the code and compared it to some solutions I found but couldn't make out the mistake so maybe you guys can help me.
Here we go:

**My Web.Config looks like this:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>


  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
      <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net"
     type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender name="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
      <file value="mylogfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".Log4NetDemoApplication_ASPXAUTH" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FriendlyName"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
          type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**In my AssemblyInfo.cs it looks like this:**

```
       #region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v4.0.30319
    // C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll
    #endregion

    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace System.Reflection
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Defines a company name custom attribute for an assembly manifest.
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, Inherited = false)]
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public sealed class AssemblyCompanyAttribute : Attribute
        {
            // Summary:
            //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute
            //     class.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   company:
            //     The company name information.
            public AssemblyCompanyAttribute(string company);

            // Summary:
            //     Gets company name information.
            //
            // Returns:
            //     A string containing the company name.
            public string Company { get; }
        }
    }
```

and last but not least the actual code looks like this:

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;

    namespace Log4NetDemoApplication.Web.Services
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for POWSTestLog
        /// </summary>
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
        // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
            public class POWSTestLog : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {
            private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
        (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            [WebMethod]
            public string TestService()
            {
                log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(POWSTestLog));


               // log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                logger.Debug("adsölkaölskd");
                log.Debug("Debug logging");
                log.Info("Info logging");
                log.Warn("Warn logging");
                log.Error("Error logging");
                log.Fatal("Fatal logging");
                return "Hello World";
            }
        }
    }

Can't look at this stuff no more =)
Thanks for all your help!
```

Answer (score 1):

Before requesting a logger you should configure it. Give it a try:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(log4netConfigPath);
ILog log4netLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyType));
```

**EDIT:** How I did it

**web.config:**

Log4net config located in the `/Config/log4net.config.xml`

**global.asax**

```
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var log4netConfigPath = Server.MapPath(
                  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["log4netConfigFilePath"]);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(log4netConfigPath) && File.Exists(log4netConfigPath))
        {
            FileInfo log4netConfig = new FileInfo(log4netConfigPath);
            if (log4netConfig != null)
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(log4netConfig);                            
                ILog log4netLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global));

                // Then register in IoC container so it would be accessible for dependency injection, etc
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // log error, etc
    }
}
```

**log4net.config.xml, file appender**

```xml
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock" />
  <param name="Threshold" value="WARN" />
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
    <conversionPattern value="logs\lf-%date{yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss}-[%processid].log" />
  </file>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
  <countDirection value="1"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %C{1}-%M - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: So if my Web.config file is in my root directory, log4netConfigPath would be: new System.IO.FileInfo ("Web.config"), right?

Comment: If this is the correct usage, I sadly have to say that it doesn't work:  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo("~/Web.config"));

Comment: See in debugger whether `var file = new System.IO.FileInfo("~/Web.config")` is not null, if null try out different ways like `new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("web.config"));`

Comment: I've added an example, basically I'm using this in my web application and all works fine

Comment: Ok, maybe I just cam closer to the identification of the problem! By using log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(log4netConfig) as you suggested, an error collection comes back which has two elements, the first saying the following: {log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Object type not specified. Cannot create object of type [log4net.Appender.IAppender]. Missing Value or Type.}

Comment: Oh and jepp, the file I pass in exists and can be altered!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8179/discussion-between-matze-and-sll)

Answer (score 1):

Why is the Configure() method commented out? It should be called to use your configuration in the web.config.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Your code should read as below

```
        [WebMethod]
        public string TestService()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(POWSTestLog));

            logger.Debug("Test log entry.");                
            return "Hello World";
        }
```

Comment: I commmented it out since I think this line in my AssembyInfo.cs I do the same thing and I don't want to adjust it twice in the my application, am I right about this?: [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="Web.config", Watch=true)]